# SSL/TLS Raw Bytes Dump

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

Does anyone know how I could easily take raw bytes and output the associated OpenSSL SSL/TLS protocol information? For example, if I simply had the bytes associated with a Server Hello message in a .bin file, is there a Linux command or tool that I could use to take the bytes and display it in a way so that each field is structure out, similar to what you would see in wireshark. The image below just shows how I would like to be able to use a Linux tool to output similar information that you would see in Wireshark from a bin file containing the associated information. The only information known is that the bin file contains TLS protocol related message information.

[image: TLS image]

Comment: I doubt that there is such a specialized command. But you might quickly create a pcap out of it and then use wireshark/tshark to analyze it. You could use perl with [Net::PcapWriter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::PcapWriter) for it but there are probably similar simple ways in Python.

Comment: Or pipe `od -vtx1` into the wireshark-provided tool `text2pcap -o -T srcport,dstport` which does what it looks like. You can even fake several frames.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: "...but if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" i feel as if wireshark is commonly used by programmers, as is openssl

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Your answer worked perfectly and gave me exactly what I was looking for. I was able to take my raw data and convert it into an ASCII hex dump. Then, doing `text2pcap -T srcport,dstport` allowed me to import the pcap and see the appropriate SSL info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With a few caveats a simple C program can do this. The caveats:

- You need to have a custom compiled version of OpenSSL 1.1.0. When building OpenSSL you need to run "config" with the "enable-ssl-trace" option
- You won't be able to handle any encrypted records this way because you won't have access to the key

With that said this program should do what you want. This program assumes that the bytes you have consist of a single record. If you've got multiple records then you'll have to split it up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Insert your raw data here. Assumes that you have a single record */
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0x16, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x04, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };
    BIO *bio_out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE | BIO_FP_TEXT);
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    int ret = 1;

    if (bio_out == NULL)
        return 1;

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_method());
    if (ctx == NULL)
        goto err;
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if (ssl == NULL)
        goto err;

    SSL_trace(0, 0, SSL3_RT_HEADER, data, SSL3_RT_HEADER_LENGTH, ssl,
             (void *)bio_out);
    SSL_trace(0, TLS1_2_VERSION, SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE,
              data + SSL3_RT_HEADER_LENGTH,
              sizeof(data) - SSL3_RT_HEADER_LENGTH, ssl,
              (void *)bio_out);

    ret = 0;

 err:
    BIO_free(bio_out);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ret;
}
```